# py4web DAL, web2py - (Legacy) database exploration - how to get all tables, fields, etc?

Tags: web2py, web2py-modules

Unfortunately there is no py4web tag (that and one for modules should be added) so i put it under web2py as DAL is the same. If someone can create a tag (maybe talking to Massimo ..) its appreciated.

Its possible to access nearly whatever database with py4web/web2py. With autoimport its not necessary to define the fields again.

```
from pydal import DAL, Field

db = DAL('sqlite://legacydb.sqlite', folder='subdirectory/additionalsubdirectory', auto_import=True)
```

Now it should be possible to get all tables, columns etc. (In Oracle: select * from all_tables, select * from user_tab_columns etc are available for this)

```
db.tables
```

Its not working. (Its said its empty but there are two tables.

```
db.person.fields
```

Even knowing that a table person is there, the fields are not shown.

But its working when the database and the tables are created and I 'aks' immediately afterwards.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

please ensure that it refer to the same database folder, with *.table available there, if run pydal on py4web or terminal ensure that you execute db.commit() if not, it just store in memory not writen on database

**e.g.**

in jupyter notebook (created two notebook, 1 for define_table with auto_import=False and the other without define_table with auto_import=True)

**notebook1**

```
from pydal import DAL, Field
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
db = DAL('sqlite://jupyter_pydal.sqlite', folder = 'databases', auto_import = False)
db.define_table('test',
    Field('string_0'),
    Field('text_0', 'text'),
    Field('integer_0', 'integer'), 
    Field('double_0', 'double'),
    Field('date_0', 'date'),
    Field('datetime_0', 'datetime'),
    #format = lambda r: f'{r.name}' )
    format = lambda r: '%s' % (r.name) )
if db(db.test).isempty():
    p0 = db.test.insert(string_0 = 'string_0', text_0 = 'text_0', integer_0 = 0, double_0 = 0, date_0 = now, datetime_0 = now)
    p1 = db.test.insert(string_0 = 'string_1', text_0 = 'text_1', integer_0 = 1, double_0 = 1, date_0 = now, datetime_0 = now)
db.commit()
db._uri
db._dbname
db.tables
db.test.fields
db.test.string_0.type
rows = db(db.test).select()
print(rows)
```

**notebook2**

```
from pydal import DAL, Field
db = DAL('sqlite://jupyter_pydal.sqlite', folder = 'databases', auto_import = True)
db._uri
db._dbname
db.tables
db.test.fields
db.test.string_0.type
rows = db(db.test).select()
print(rows)
```

**result for command**

```
db._uri
db._dbname
db.tables
db.test.fields
db.test.string_0.type
rows = db(db.test).select()
print(rows)
```

on notebook2 is same like notebook1

but when remove *.table on database folder and rerun notebook2 the result for

```
db.tables
db.test.fields
db.test.string_0.type
rows = db(db.test).select()
print(rows)
```

is not found on notebook2

**ref for pydal on web2py site**

http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Using-DAL-without-define-tables

Comment: Steve, what do you mean by: *.tables?

Comment: Steve, what do you mean by: *.tables?
But the central question or idea. Suppose I have access rights to all tables in the database which can be a limiting factor in Oracle. 
I would interpret: 
'If we just need access to the data but not to the web2py table attributes, we get away without re-defining the tables but simply asking web2py to read the necessary info from the metadata in the .table files:
..
This allows us to access any db.table without need to re-define it.'
so that I access a database (with necessary access rights) and ask what tables are there? Getting all table names.

Comment: *.table is a file created when a database table is created with pydal, and will be updated if you have modified your define_table. 
please take a look into your databases folder then you will see *.table and sql.log files

Comment: I did not find a file *.table in the file directory. 
What I always have is a file for each table. But not inside the SQL commands. 
But what i found:
SELECT name FROM sqlite_master
WHERE type='table'
Thats the corresponding to the Oracle select all_tables command.

Comment: The log file is there when I use py4web (web2py) but not when i use the pyDAL component through jupyter notebooks.

Comment: not enough info why you couldnt see *.table, it usually created by pydal either it standalone module or within any others framework included on jupyter env, so basically *.table contain information that represent what was written on the define_table. quick conclusion is when not define_table and set auto_import=True, the pydal will see the contain of *.table, and can communicate with the table (like example given above)